# Go application run in production

Tags: linux

I have a production server with ssh root access. There I have installed go and  have cloned my project, I am working with putty to run my application but after closing putty my go application stops working, what I need to do to get always running go application?

Here is my go.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=my amazing service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=go run /root/work/src/main/main.go

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing at a lot of details, you're probably ssh'ing in, starting your program at the command line and closing the connection. What's happening is normal session termination in Unix: when the login shell exits, all of the running processes under it are sent a `HUP` signal (short for "hangup", dating back to when a dropped connection meant that the phone line connected to the machine had been hung up).

If all you wanted to do was run it once in a while and didn't mind having to restart it manually, then you could use the `nohup` command to prevent the end of your login session from causing the program to terminate.

```
nohup go run your-program &
```

This runs your program in the background, and blocks it from receiving the `HUP` signal. You can now disconnect your SSH session and the program will continue to run.

If this program is meant to be an always-up, continuously-running service – and because you mention "production", I'll assume it is – use @kichik's solution. `nohup` is *not* a reasonable way to run a production server. Use @kichik's way to do it *right*. This answer is just so you understand why your current method isn't working.

Comment: That's exactly what I would have answered.

Answer (score 8):

For recent versions of Ubuntu create `/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service` with:

```
[Unit]
Description=my amazing service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
ExecStart=/usr/bin/path/to/my/service some args

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Run this one time:

```
systemctl enable myservice
```

You can then start and stop your service with:

```
sudo systemctl start myservice
sudo systemctl stop myservice
```

It will also start automatically when the server boots, and restart if it crashes.

More here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Example_Systemd_service

There are many other service management solutions, but systemd comes with Ubuntu 16 so it's probably the easiest to use.

Comment: I have created service as you said but when trying to start it I am getting the following error Failed to start go.service: Unit go.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.

Comment: Check `/var/log/*` for errors and make sure you ran `sudo systemctl enable go`

Comment: I havel already runed `sudo systemctl enable go` and in logs there is nothing

Comment: "not loaded properly" suggests `systemctl enable` failed somehow. If there is nothing in the logs, maybe in the output of `journalctl`?

Comment: I have added my file on above

Comment: It might help to include the full path to `go`. Also, in general, it makes more sense to run a compiled service rather than compiling it when it starts. It'll be faster, less fragile, and will remove the requirement of a go compiler on your server.

Comment: what I need to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Like kichik said, you can write a systemd script. As an alternative, you can use [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/). It can automatically start your application when the server boots and it supports automatic restart of the application when it crashes.

You can also create a [Docker image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) and deploy your application in a Docker container.

Comment: Docker is wayyyyy overkill just to get a service running.

Comment: As is supervisor. _Every_ Linux distribution comes with an init system, be it the "old" [SYS V init](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit), [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) or [openrc](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:OpenRC). It makes no sense whatsoever to introduce a daemon to keep a process running which in turn needs to be started by the init system - rather use the init system right away.